# How to communicate with the controller using AJAX in Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm using **CodeIgniter** for over a year now (and got pretty used to it) then found out that it is getting outdated and *support has been taken off by ellislab*. I want to try using **Laravel** as an alternative though *CodeIgniter still works just fine* but for Future purposes, I don't want to get left behind. Now, with Laravel's MVC framework it was easy for me to migrate some of my projects from CI. I'm having a problem with Laravel's routing though as **I'm not able to communicate with my controller**. Here's a bit of my code:

`controller.php`:

```
public function connect() {
    $this->load->model('home_model');
    if ($DBconnect=$this->home_model->checkConnection()) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "success" => true,
            "db_connect" => $DBconnect
        ));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "success" => false,
            "db_connect" => $DBconnect
        ));
    }
}
```

`view.js`:

```
    $("#connection").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        show_loading();
        $.get('./home/connect', function(data) {
            hide_loading();
            Materialize.toast(data.db_connect, 4000, 'rounded green');
        }, "json");
    });
```

**PS:** *Am I doing the Laravel way or I'm still very CI minded?*

Comment: what version of laravel you were using? you need to learn how use use route in laravel.

Comment: i'm using 4.2.11 @RomnickSusa, yeah that's why I came here :D

Comment: Laravel 4.2 has a good documentation for this. Did you open this http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#basic-routing?

Comment: actually I'm reading it right now.

Comment: Try my answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to connect with the controller

First set up the routes.php :

```
Route::controller('/','MyController');
```

On the controller app/controller/MyController.php (You need to create one) :

```
<?php

class MyController extends BaseController {
    public function getJustASampleText(){
        echo "Hello World";
    }
    public function getJustASampleSmile(){
        echo ":D";
    }
    public function getConnect(){
        $var_value = "Hello world";
        return Response::json(array('var_name' => $var_value));
    }
}
```

Then you can call that function like this

`domain.com/just-a-sample-text` or

`domain.com/just-a-sample-smile`or in you case

```
$.get(`http://127.0.0.1/laravel/public/connect`,function(data){
    alert(data.var_name);
})
```

That how we use Route::controller approach.

Comment: is `dash (-)` really necessary?

Comment: you mean like this? `$.get('localhost/connect', function(data) {`

Comment: Yes, and don't forget the capitalization. You need to name your function like this `method type + camel case name`.

Comment: I tried `$.get('http://127.0.0.1/laravel/public/connect', function(data) {`, but it doesnt seem to be getting any data from the controller.

Comment: with `Route::controller('/','Home');` on `Route.php`

Comment: in your Route::controller('/','Home');, Do you have a controller named Home?